# Extra column inserted before other columns when exporting to excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I know how tricky it is to align things in a way that allows a clean export to excel, however, on this one I am stumped and have never seen it before.

Anyone know why the excel rendering extension insists on inserting a column like in the attached image?

Things that I have tried.

1. Set the table's position to 0,0.
2. Removed all borders and padding.
3. Set the report margins to 0,0,0,0

NOTE : I am using the EXCELOPENXML rendering format as opposed to EXCEL in order to support *.xlxs.

[image]

Groupings:

[image]

First Column in the Designer:

[image]

Comment: Just taking a stab.. you don't have any merged columns at the beginning by any chance?

Comment: No, The only merged columns were the ones for the row added as the header for column group (OneRecord) above, however, I deleted that entire Row, hence the parentheses.

Comment: I think you are on the right lines. Is there anything in the "OneRecord" group or is it just a container for the child groups? If it's just a container, can you remove that group. I've had situations where you can't see elements in the design but they appeared in the .rdl and reomving the parent item was the only way to get rid of them cleanly. Worth a shot I guess.

Comment: After breaking the report down to one column with no groups, it still occurred. Then, out of nowhere, a bright bolt of brilliance hit me when I remembered this was being rendered as a sub report. When I checked the main report I realized that the sub report was in a rectangle had been scooted one twip from the edge :/ Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

The report was being rendered as a sub report and was placed in a rectangle and aligned right in the main report, however, the rectangle was one twip off from left align. Once I aligned the rectangle in the main report, the phantom column disappeared.